# Writing a functor in C

Tags: c, function, functional-programming, functor

I want to make something like this in C:

```
typedef int (*func)(int);

func make_adder(int a) {
  int add(int x) {
    return a + x;
  }
  return &add;
}

int main() {
  func add_42 = make_adder(42);
  // add_42(10) == 52
}
```

But this doesn't work. Is it doable? Where is my mistake?

Comment: Closures are not supported in `C`, it is not doable, not if you need to call it using the `()` operator.

Comment: nested functions are not standard C.

Comment: What would be the best way to emulate it, though (if there is one)?

Comment: In what way is this a functor?

Comment: @naomik I went by this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/356993/1350864

Answer (score 6):

No, this is not possible, because there's nowhere in memory where that `int a` could be stored in such a way that `&add` refers to it. `int a` exists on the function stack of `make_adder` and does not survive, so `&add` cannot be referring to the original. Making a copy of `int a` is impossible because the lifetime of that copy would need to be tied to that of `&add`, and C doesn't have the necessary Garbage Collection for that.

So, in conclusion, we cannot save either the original stack variable `a` or make a copy on the heap.

Comment: Thank you. But this code was supposed to be representative of what I want to do, not how would I go about implementing it. Can I implement a functor/closure in C, in any other way, or at least emulate that behaviour?

Comment: @andrepd: Of course you can provide the storage yourself: `struct closure{ int a; int (*fun)(int, int); }` and `int call(struct closure*, int x)`.

Comment: Hmm, that makes sense! I guess I was too tied up with the function() syntax that I overlooked the obvious. In C++ I could do that and overload `operator()`, but here I guess that does it ;)